# How many apk can I upload to google play & admob

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, admob

hello I will get a membership to install the google playe apk for 25 dollars. There are some questions I wonder.

1. What is the application install limit? Can I install as many apk as I want?
2. What problems do I have when I add two banners to the APK? is this forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You pay a onetime 25$ payment for a developer account. With this you can release as many Apps as you want. No time limit.
2. You can add as much advertisement as you want in your apps. The other things is if the users will like it. Make sure you don't go against admob policy.

Comment: Well how many applications can I install at most?

Comment: There are no limits on applications. Google will take a 30% fee of IAPs.